LSM303AGR burnt, help find the schematic error
I am just testing the board, it was working fine but after some 3-4 hours, I noticed the 3V3 had shorted to GND, I was measuring 0.5V on the power source. I inspected with a thermal camera and the LSM303AGR acelerometer section was hot (60 degrees). Something eventually burnt out (white smoke), and the short was no longer there and 3V3 was again at 3V3. Strange because the acelerometer was suposed to be OFF and I was doing unrelated measurements on the board.
This is the schematic:

Layout:

After the white smoke, these are some of the voltages with MPU_PWR_CTRL LOW:
Q9: Gate = Source = 3.3V, Drain = 0.55. Also the 0.55 "moves" it peaks to 1V sometimes.
C20: Measuring 224nF and infinite resistance but it has a suspicious black mark. When the board is powered (3V3 at 0.55V), the voltage oscilates between 0.5 and 0.8V. part: CL10B224KA8NNNC (datasheet recomends ESR lower than 200mohm)
U12 is 10C over ambient Temperature.
With MPU_PWR_CTRL HIGH:
Q9: Gate = 0V, Source = 3.3V, Drain = 3.3V.
C20: 3V
U12 is 40C over ambient Temperature.
SCL at 3V3 through a 10k resistor. But SDA is 1.2V, dont know why.
MAG INT and MPU INT go to D7 and D3 on a particle photon MCU, they are at the default state.


Probably not your issue, but the DMP4065 PFET could have a threshold voltage as low as -3 V, so with the tolerance on your 3.3 V rail and the Vce sat of the 3904 you could be very close to not being able to turn it on (if you had one near the edge of spec).  You certainly wouldn't get the RDSon quoted in the datasheet under any circumstances.

Current consumption of this device is pretty low, so the PFET not being fully enhanced might not be an issue, but if you're building a lot of these you may get one that doesn't turn on.

Thanks for mentioning I will replace it, but yes I dont think it is the problem, since it burnt when the pfet was off

One of the problem could be that some of the pins are connected to 3V3 and some to 3V3_MPU. You need to check datasheet if chip can tolerate different voltages on these pins.

The footprint and pins look good. One problem I see is there are no vias that go to ground for C20, C19 and C18. I don't see any traces routed out from the ground pad or vias in pad. This could be messing up the chip.
You might be able to 'blue wire' them. Use a very thick wire and make the runs as short as you can to minimize inductance

Good observation! You can see the edges of a what is presumably a GND-pour but no connection from the pads to that put either... Might have lead to a latch up somewhere which would also be consistent with the 0.5V seen instead of the plain short....

The top and bottom layer has ground filled in unused space, it is not shown for clarity
